# Anonymize continuous variable for masking purposes

Tags: masking, transformation

I am about to kick off a large hackathon event.

We have a dataset that is comprised of one continuous variable with high precision, and a number of categorical variables qualifying these data 3-levels deep.

Data provider wants to 'mask' the data such that the original values cannot be reverse-engineered.  I'm not worried about the categorical variables, this is simple.  But the continuous variables are tricky.

1. a logarithmic transformation is easily reverse engineered
2. a nonlinear transformation is better, but will mess with the relationship of values between categories
3. a pure linear transformation would work, but doesn't seem to 'mask' enough.

I need to preserve the relationships between numbers whilst also protecting the actual, true values.

Ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: theoreticaly any one-one transformation is invertible (no matter linear or not), on the other hand a not one-one transformation messes up the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a much more complicated monotonic transformation, like

```r
log(1.234578 + sqrt(x + 7.4142) ** 3)
```

which will be harder to invert than a simple log. But, as Nikos says, strictly monotonic functions are invertible, so all you can do is make it very hard to compute the inverse by composing many monotonic functions.

Comment: maybe use some "unique" hash (cryptographic) function with unique key/salt?

Comment: is it possible not to lose the monotonicity? can you provide an example?

Comment: I like this approach, but doesn't this transform, while monotonic, screw with the relationships between numbers?  e.g., a regression run on the transformed numbers won't yield the same parameter estimates as the original numbers, right?

Comment: yeah, the parameters will change, but they change when you apply a logarithm too. However, given a model you'll always be able to recover the model on the original variables by calculating the inverse of the transformation function

Comment: I implied using a "one-one" cryptographic hash (with unique key/salt) as the desired transform, but..

Comment: Is there any reason to NOT just rescale everything between 0/1?